# Enable port and port forwarding for a site collection in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I would like to know about the port enabling and port forwarding to make the sharepoint site collection out side the network. 
Assume, i have created a web application on the port 3333.and my system is having static ip as well. Now how to enable this port and how to make the url as http : // server name instaed of http : //server name:3333